# 'str' object is not callable but no variable str in the code

Tags: python, selenium, runtime-error, variable-assignment

I am new to Python and this website. I wanted to know if someone can help with this. I have this code here but I only get the error below. I searched in the internet but I don't have a variable called *str*. Thanks for helping.

## Code

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

username = "***"
password = "***"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("***")

driver.find_element(By.NAME("_username")).send_keys(username)
```

## Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deniz/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.NAME("_username")).send_keys(username)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What type of object is `By.NAME`?  (Do `print(type(By.NAME))` if you aren't sure.)

Comment: @Samwise it's a string contains "name"

Comment: That’s a `str` And you can’t call it like a function with `("_username")`. That’s what the error message is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

`(By.NAME, "_username")` not `(By.NAME("_username"))`

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

username = "***"
password = "***"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("***")

driver.find_element(By.NAME, "_username").send_keys(username)
```